# for each data jquery ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to send data to php using jquery ajax. The problem is in the below code.
(You can ignore php)
**HTML**

```
<ul class="blah">
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>4</li>
</ul>
<div class="result"></div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(".blah li").each(function(){
  var each_li = $(this).text();
});

$.ajax({
    url: 'select-query.php',
    method: 'POST',
    data: {li_variable: each_li},
    success: function(response){
        $('.result').html(response);
    }
});
```

**each_li** returns only one value in ajax function. I can put the ajax in each function but for every li element it performs ajax call. How can i  give all li values to ajax data &  call ajax only once.
**PHP(select-query.php)**

```
<?
$query = "SELECT username FROM table WHERE id = '".$_POST['li_variable']."'";
$query_run = mysqli_query($connect,$query);
while($query_array = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_run)){
    echo $query_array['username'];
}
?>
```

Comment: You want an array of data?

Comment: use `each_li[]` and declare `each_li` as array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can push the data into an array and then send it in ajax request as follows:

```
var each_li = [];
$(".blah li").each(function(){
   each_li.push($(this).text()); //pushing the data in js array
});

$.ajax({
    url: 'select-query.php',
    method: 'POST',
    data: {li_variable: each_li},
    success: function(response){
        $('.result').html(response);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can collect all the element's text content by using [`map`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) and [`get`](http://api.jquery.com/get/),

```
var each_li = $(".blah li").map(function(){
  return this.textContent;
}).get();
```

Do not fear about `.get` by thinking that it will do another one iteration to collect the preserved values. It will simply unwrap that value collection from the Jquery object. No iteration will happen under the hood.

Comment: Nice and short, the simplicity is strong with this one!

Answer (score 0):

Create array of li values and send array in ajax:

```
myArray = new Array();
cnt = 0;
$(".blah li").each(function(){
      myArray[cnt] = $(this).text();
cnt++;
});
var jsonString = JSON.stringify(myArray);

$.ajax({
    url: 'select-query.php',
    method: 'POST',
    data: {li_variable: jsonString},
    success: function(response){
        $('.result').html(response);
    }
});
```

In php:

```
$data = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['li_variable']));

  foreach($data as $d){
     echo $d;
  }
```